# JSON Decode array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get data from JSON array.

```
<?php


$query = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD&to_currency=JPY&apikey=demo";


$forexdecode = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($forexdecode);
echo '</pre>';


$GBPUSD = $forexdecode->"Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"->"5. Exchange Rate";?>'
```

I have no problems getting data printed using print_r. I get:

> stdClass Object
>   (
>       [Realtime Currency Exchange Rate] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [1. From_Currency Code] => USD
>               [2. From_Currency Name] => United States Dollar
>               [3. To_Currency Code] => JPY
>               [4. To_Currency Name] => Japanese Yen
>               [5. Exchange Rate] => 109.72200000
>               [6. Last Refreshed] => 2019-02-10 07:26:32
>               [7. Time Zone] => UTC
>           )
>   )

but when I try to get data into variable $GBPUSD I get blank page.

How do I get data from this API?

```
 [5. Exchange Rate]
```

Comment: You need to use `{}` notation: `$GBPUSD = $forexdecode->{"Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"}->{"5. Exchange Rate"};`

Comment: It worked. Thank you